# How to get console.getkey of 2 users

Tags: .net, f#

I'm trying to learn F# by making a game, Tron.
So it's a multiplayer game and I need to have a console key reader for both players. One use ZQSD, the other the arrows.

```
    let mutable switchb = new pos(-1, 0)
    let mutable switcha = new pos(1, 0)
    let key_info = Console.ReadKey().Key
        if key_info = ConsoleKey.UpArrow then
           switchb.y <- switchb.y - 1
        else if key_info = ConsoleKey.DownArrow then
           switchb.y <- switchb.y + 1
        else if key_info = ConsoleKey.RightArrow then
           switchb.x <- switchb.x + 1
        else if key_info = ConsoleKey.LeftArrow then
           switchb.x <- switchb.x - 1
        if key_info = ConsoleKey.Z then
           switcha.y <- switcha.y - 1
        else if key_info = ConsoleKey.S then
           switcha.y <- switcha.y + 1
        else if key_info = ConsoleKey.D then
           switcha.x <- switcha.x + 1
        else if key_info = ConsoleKey.Q then
           switcha.x <- switcha.x - 1
```

The problem is that I can only have one input by loop round.

Do I need to make a thread which catch the input of a second player ? I don't know what can I do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why can you only have one input per loop iteration?

Comment: Console.ReadKey().Key returns only one input that I have to compare then. Do you suggest to do 2 ReadKey() in the same loop ?

EDIT: Oh no, you're asking about the loop ! I have to make a loop to check if the user send an input. If not, the "snake" will move alone in the last direction pressed (right for right arrow for instance). So there is a loop with a sleep to make a game round.

Comment: Unfortunately, `Console.ReadKey()` isn't meant for what you're trying to use it for. There are Win32 API functions which will let you know if multiple keys are pressed - check out this blog post: http://www.aaronlerch.com/blog/2006/10/10/get-key-state-from-a-console-application/

Comment: Ok, so there is a Keyboard.IsKeyDown method in F#. Thank you.

Comment: I'll try to transform this in F# now.